# nc.call() closes the netconnection

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, connection, flash-builder, flash-media-server

i have made a flash chat application on Flash Builder 4.6 which connects to Flash Media (Development) Server on my centos5 32bit server, the problem is when i leave it open in browser about 2 minutes idle, then trying to call the netconnection to get the chat history or to send a public message or to invoke a function at the serverside with the nc.call() method, it suddenly says netconnection.connect.closed.. UNLESS i call, it doesnt gives me a connenction.closed event..

while this happening, i am looking at the fms admin console for active users, but the client doesnt drop and seems still connected to server..even i close the browser, client is still there in the fms console.. (normally, when i close the browser or when i use the nc.close() the client disconnects and i see the quick change in the fms admin console..

then still watching the fms admin console, after about 10 minutes the client drops..(it is normal i think)

i tried the same app with the connection to localhost, it works very well, i left the app open for a very long time idle, and then tried the nc.call() it worked fine..  but when i try the app on the my server, i had the problem.. i tried both fms 3.5 and 4.0.3 on my server but i had the problem too.. but on localhost it works so i think the problem is not about versions it is about something different with the connection to the server..

also the pepper flash player is disabled..and the problem is not about the autocloseidleclients property in the server.xml, application.xml vhost.xml config files. the problem is something different with the connection may be about firewall, tcp, router etc.. i dont know but i really need help..

thanks for reading..

Answer (score 0):

Hm, if `NetConnection` works using sockets, then as far as I know, on Windows, the only way you can determine if a socket is closed is to try and write something to it; if it fails, then it's been closed - hence `call()` actually closing the connection after it's been idle for too long.

When you close the browser or call `nc.close()`, it's a specific request - normally on the server you'd also implement something like "if I haven't received anything in X seconds, disconnect the socket", which would trigger a callback on the client end.

I'd implement a sort of keep-alive; every 15/30 seconds, send a simple ping to the server, which will keep your connection open.